# Unable to read from a .dat file in C

Tags: c, file-handling

I have created a program which takes account information from the user and stores it into the file *accounts.dat*. As the program is right now, it appears everything works fine until I close it and reopen to test it out, it doesn't read off any of the information that I had already entered. Case 6 is where it is supposed to read from the *accounts.dat*. *accounts.dat* does seem to be filling up with information, each time I use it.

```
/* HEADER FILES */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* STRUCT TO HOLD ACCOUNT INFO */
struct bank
{
    char first[25];
    char middle[25];
    char last[25];
    long int aNumber;
    float aBalance;
};

/* MAIN START*/
int main()
{
    int choice; /* SWITCH-STATEMENT CASE */
    int i; /* FOR-LOOP COUNTER */
    int  count; /* KEEPS TRACK OF TOTAL # OF ACCOUNTS */
    long int aNumber; /* TEMPORARILY HOLDS ACCOUNT # FOR SEARCH IN FILE */
    float amount; /* TEMPORARILY HOLDS A DOLLAR AMOUNT FOR VARIOUS REASONS */
    FILE *fp; /* SPECIFIC FILE DECLARATION FOR OUR BANK */
    struct bank account[50]; /* ARRAY DECLARATION FOR STRUCT */

    /* DO/WHILE START */
    do
    {
        /* OPTION MENU */
        printf("\n\nWelcome to yor bank access.\n"
               "Please follow the prompts below.\n\n"
               "\t0. Exit\n"
               "\t1. Deposit\n"
               "\t2. Withdrawal\n"
               "\t3. Add account\n"
               "\t4. Remove Account\n"
               "\t5. Balance Inquiry\n"
               "\t6. View Account\n"
               "\nEnter your choice: ");
        scanf("%d",&choice);
        printf("\n");

        /* SWITCH START */
        switch(choice)
        {

        /* CASE 0: EXIT PROGRAM */
        case 0:
            exit(1);
            break;

        /* CASE 1: DEPOSIT */
        case 1:
            fopen("accounts.dat", "r+");
            fseek(fp,0,SEEK_SET);
            printf("please enter account number: ");
            scanf("%ld",&aNumber);
            printf("Amount to be deposited: $");
            scanf("%f", &amount);
            for(i=0; i<count; i++)
            {
                if(account[i].aNumber == aNumber)
                {
                    account[i].aBalance = account[i].aBalance + amount;
                    fseek(fp,i * sizeof(struct bank),SEEK_SET);
                    fwrite(account+i,sizeof(struct bank),1, fp);
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(i==count)
                printf("Account number does not exits\n");
            break;

        /* CASE:2 WITHDRAWAL */
        case 2:
            fopen("accounts.dat", "r+");
            fseek(fp,0,SEEK_SET);
            printf("Please enter account number: ");
            scanf("%ld",&aNumber);
            printf("Enter the amount to be withdrawn: $");
            scanf("%f",&amount);
            for(i=0; i<count; i++)
            {
                if(account[i].aNumber==aNumber)
                {
                    if(account[i].aBalance<amount)
                    {
                        printf("Insufficient balance\n");
                        break;
                    }
                    account[i].aBalance=account[i].aBalance-amount;
                    fseek(fp,i*sizeof(struct bank),SEEK_SET);
                    fwrite(account+i,sizeof(struct bank),1, fp);
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(i==count)
                printf("Account number does not exits\n");
            break;

        /* CASE 3: ADD ACCOUNT */
        case 3:
            fp = fopen("accounts.dat","a+");
            printf("Enter a 6-digit account number: ");
            scanf("%ld",&aNumber);
            for(i=0; i<count; i++)
            {
                if(account[i].aNumber==aNumber)
                {
                    printf("Account already exist\n");
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(i==count)
            {
                account[i].aNumber=aNumber;

                printf("Enter the First Name: ");
                scanf("%s",account[i].first);

                printf("Enter the Middle Initial: ");
                scanf("%s",account[i].middle);

                printf("Enter the Last Name: ");
                scanf("%s",account[i].last);

                printf("Enter the Amount: $");
                scanf("%f",&account[i].aBalance);
                fseek(fp,0,SEEK_END);
                fwrite(account+i,sizeof(struct bank),1, fp);
                count++;
            }
            break;

        /* CASE 4: DELETE ACCOUNT */
        case 4:
            fopen("accounts.dat", "a+");
            fseek(fp,0,SEEK_SET);
            printf("Please enter account number: ");
            scanf("%ld",&aNumber);
            for(i=0; i<count; i++)
            {
                if(account[i].aNumber==aNumber)
                    break;
            }
            if(i==count)
                printf("Account number does not exits\n");
            else
            {
                while(i<count)
                {
                    strcpy(account[i].first,account[i+1].first);
                    strcpy(account[i].middle,account[i+1].middle);
                    strcpy(account[i].last,account[i+1].last);
                    account[i].aNumber=account[i+1].aNumber;
                    account[i].aBalance=account[i+1].aBalance;
                }
                count--;
                fp=fopen("accounts.dat", "wb");
                for(i=0; i<count; i++)
                    fwrite(account+i,sizeof(struct bank),1, fp);
                fclose(fp);
                /* REOPEN FILE */
                fopen("accounts.dat", "r+");
            }
            break;

        /* CASE 5: BALANCE INQUIRY*/
        case 5:
            fopen("accounts.dat", "r");
            printf("Please enter account number: ");
            scanf("%ld",&aNumber);
            for(i=0; i<count; i++)
            {
                if(account[i].aNumber==aNumber)
                {
                    printf("First Name: %s\n",account[i].first);
                    printf("Middle Initial: %s\n",account[i].middle);
                    printf("Last Name: %s\n",account[i].last);
                    printf("Account Number: %ld\n",account[i].aNumber);
                    printf("Balance Amount: $%.2f\n",account[i].aBalance);
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(i==count)
                printf("Account number does not exits\n");
            break;

        /* CASE 6: VIEW ACCOUNTS*/
        case 6:
            fopen("accounts.dat", "r");
            for(i=0; i<count; i++)
            {
                fread(&account[i], sizeof(account), 1, fp);
                printf("Entry %1d\n", i+1);
                printf("First Name: %s\n",account[i].first);
                printf("Middle Initial: %s\n",account[i].middle);
                printf("Last Name: %s\n",account[i].last);
                printf("Account Number: %ld\n",account[i].aNumber);
                printf("Account Balance: $%.2f\n",account[i].aBalance);
            }
        } /* END SWITCH-STATEMENT */
    } /* END 'DO' */
    while(choice!=0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You must **validate the return** on every `scanf` , e.g. `scanf("%s",account[i].first);` (or any input function for that point) to insure you are actually processing valid data. Check the return.

Comment: That's far from a [mcve]. Read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

When you start the program with case 6, the `count` is not initialized, leading to unexpected behavior of the `for` loop.

Comment: Not just case 6. The `i < count` test is used in 6 different locations, but `count` is never initialized in a single place throughout the code.

Answer (score -1):

As has been pointed out, count hasn't been initialised, but will typically start with a value of zero, when you exit the program and restart it later. While this isn't guaranteed, if it's zero you'll find the loops will terminate early.

So on a restart what you need to do is read back the number of records in your dat file and initialise count to that number, then everything should work from there. You might want to create a new option “read in existing file” or similar to do the scan.